# Celery ensure tasks run on different nodes

Tags: python, celery

I started working with Celery and I got a basic understanding of routing queues and I have a question about that.

I have a Redis instance, with a variable number of nodes running tasks from the same broker. Attached to each node is a mongodb for storing results. There are 3 types of tasks Celery runs on each node, one type which I want to be run on different nodes.

In other words for example, if there are the following nodes each one of them having 4 workers:

- node1, node2, node3

And the following list of tasks added into the queue:

1. task_type1
2. task_type2
3. special_task
4. special_task
5. task_type2
6. ....

What I want is that when one node will take the first 3 tasks, will not take task 4 because I don't want it run on the same node, but instead any other node can pick task 4 as long it does not have another `special_task` already running on that node.

How can this be archived, is there another way to restructure the architecture, or it can be managed only from the code.

Thanks.

Comment: The only way to achieve what you want is to start using queues. Subscribe different workers (running on different nodes) to specific queue(s) and then send the right task to the right queue.

Comment: That sounds good, but what if I have a variable number of nodes, that could increase or decrease over time? This would mean that I need to create queues dynamically and add a new queue for a new node if I understood correctly.